# Overwrite selecting word when using the jquery plugin Tokeninput

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-tokeninput

I use the jquery plugin Tokeninput that allow autocomplete in textBox. I would overwrite selecting word. So the list of autocomplete must contains one word.

Does anybody have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Tokeninput docs](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

**resultsLimit** - The maximum number of results shown in the drop down. Use null to show all the matching results. default: null

But you can also control your response by server-side

**EDIT:**

Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, then please give me more information about what you trying to do. code source would be helpful